# linux flex gcc compile fails with `undefined reference to `TclReError'`

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, flex-lexer

I am having some issues compiling flex from source. The configure is being passed 
`CC=/home/mybin/bin/gcc CPPFLAGS=-I/home/mybin/include LDFLAGS=-L/home/mybin/lib`.

Within ../include i have two files containing references

```
regex.h:110:#define regerror    TclReError
regcustom.h:78:#define  regerror    TclReError
```

when running config, no error is produced and nothing of interest in the logs, however make throws an error

```
     /bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link /home/mybin/bin/gcc  -g -O2  -L/home/mybin/lib -o flex ccl.o dfa.o ecs.o scanflags.o gen.o main.o misc.o nfa.o parse.o scan.o skel.o sym.o tblcmp.o yylex.o options.o scanopt.o buf.o tables.o tables_shared.o filter.o regex.o ../lib/libcompat.la -lm 
libtool: link: /home/mybin/bin/gcc -g -O2 -o flex ccl.o dfa.o ecs.o scanflags.o gen.o main.o misc.o nfa.o parse.o scan.o skel.o sym.o tblcmp.o yylex.o options.o scanopt.o buf.o tables.o tables_shared.o filter.o regex.o  -L/home/_bin/lib ../lib/.libs/libcompat.a -lm
regex.o: In function `flex_regcomp':
/home/tmp/flex-2.6.0/src/regex.c:66: undefined reference to `TclReError'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [flex] Error 1
```

in configure --help no reference is made to explicit flags

```
Some influential environment variables:

  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH
              User-defined run-time library search path.
  CPP         C preprocessor
  YACC        The `Yet Another Compiler Compiler' implementation to use.
              Defaults to the first program found out of: `bison -y', `byacc',
              `yacc'.
  YFLAGS      The list of arguments that will be passed by default to $YACC.
              This script will default YFLAGS to the empty string to avoid a
              default value of `-d' given by some make applications.
  CXX         C++ compiler command
  CXXFLAGS    C++ compiler flags
  CXXCPP      C++ preprocessor
```

I have also tried exporting directly with `export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/mybin/include"`

extended searches on SO and google have returned noting obvious, any pointers on what I am missing?

Comment: Get rid of double quotes and give it a shot: `export CPPFLAGS=-I/home/mybin/include`

Comment: tried both quoted and unquoted, same error. Also tried setting explicitly in a bash script just before calling make. no luck

Comment: Did you try with `CFLAGS` instead of `CPPFLAGS`?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick downloaded from http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/flex/flex-2.6.0.tar.gz, straight tar -xzf flex-2.6.0.tar.gz. Did you have a different repo i could try?

Comment: Both packets are identical compared with beyond compare

Comment: Coalescing and shortening my previous comments: your source code for flex is OK, but the addition of `CPPFLAGS=-I/home/mybin/include` means that the #include of `regex.h` (from `flexdef.h` from `regex.c`) is coming from that directory, which appears to have the `regex.h` from the Tcl distribution rather than the `regex.h` that one would expect to see in the standard `/usr/include` directory. If you do need to include that `-I/home/mybin/include` option, add a `-I/path/to/standard/include/directory` option to the left of it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, the duplicate from tcl was the problem. Deleting it makes the compile ok. Still struggling to have both coexist. I tried adding `CPPFLAGS=-I/home/tmp/flex-2.6.0/src CPPFLAGS=-I/home/mybin/include` but config complained about the space. How do I add an `-I` option to the left? is it just without a space, ie `CPP..../src-I/home...`

Comment: Which version of tcl/tk did you install, and how? I don't see how you would end up with TCL's private regex.h in a supposedly public directory.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: You put a space between them, which means you need to quote the variable assignment: `CPPFLAGS="-I/some/path -I/some/other/path"` (or you can quote the whole thing. Or just the space: `CPPFLAGS=-I/some/path" "-I/some/other/path`)

Comment: @rici, thanks for the breadcrumb, turns out for another package the `make install-private-headers` was set and these got included in the image. this has now been removed from the build.

Answer (score 2):

you set them as an environment variable; configure determines **LDFLAGS** and **CPPFLAGS** by checking config files and the environment. You can try like this.

```
  export CPPFLAGS='-I/home/mybin/include'
  export LDFLAGS='-L/home/mybin/lib'
  ./configure
```

**or as a one-liner:**

```
 env CPPFLAGS='-I/home/mybin/include' LDFLAGS='-L/home/mybin/lib' ./configure
```

Please try this...

Comment: interesting, I tried it as one liner rather than a bash script & got a slightly different output `regex.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `TclReError'`